# bnpFromString js equivalent of php Math_BigInteger?

Tags: javascript, php, rsa, phpseclib

BigInteger - subset useful for RSA encryption.
JS LIb - Tom Wu, and PHP Lib - phpseclib
In the Js Lib input can pass an array, for example - http://js.do/code/biginteger
As a php library to pass the same array and get the same result?
If the php library to pass an array like this

```
new Math_BigInteger(implode('', $buffer), 256);
```

The result will be different

```
12**557**......
```

Please, help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
new Math_BigInteger(implode('', array_map('chr', $buffer)), 256);
```